# Ubuntu SSL connection with TLS connection error

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, tls, curl, wget

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, installed at VirtualBox (Mac) using vagrant. I am not using any proxy server.

In my company network, when I try

```
curl -1vsS https://github.com/FGRibreau/doxx/archive/master.zip
```

I get the following results:

```
* About to connect() to github.com port 443 (#0)                                                                                           
*   Trying 192.30.252.130... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:443
```

It stucked at Client hello.
Same goes with other tools I am using e.g. npm, bower

But if I do the following:

```
wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1 https://github.com/FGRibreau/doxx/archive/master.zip
```

I am able to download the file. 
The major issue here is I only get the connection problem if I am in my company network. The problem mentioned never occurred if I connected at other network. (e.g. home, public Internet access, and etc.)

Before I get around the issue by forcing all connections using SSLv3 as the problem only happens if client/server decided to use TLS.

I assume it is because of the recent SSL vulnerability that people starting to disable SSLv3.

Anything I can do to check whats wrong with my setup that causes problem when using TLS for HTTPS connections?

[Edit]
If I do the following command:

```
strace -o ./tmp.out curl -v -sS https://github.com/FGRibreau/doxx/archive/master.zip
```

The tmp.out is too huge to paste it here, so the last few lines are:

```
write(3, "\26\3\1\0\337\1\0\0\333\3\2T`E\30\3006\315\336\220I\6|\v'!8cp*\206\332"..., 228) = 228
write(2, "*", 1)                        = 1
write(2, " ", 1)                        = 1
write(2, "SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hel"..., 40) = 40
read(3, 0x9cdf3e0, 7)                   = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10742, 580346821}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10742, 580375417}) = 0
poll([{fd=3, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLRDNORM|POLLRDBAND}], 1, 299700) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (To be restarted)
--- SIGINT (Interrupt) @ 0 (0) ---
+++ killed by SIGINT +++
```

It seems like is waiting for server to response, but didn't get it and exited with error.

Comment: For some reasons all of my recent questions are down voted. Will be glad if anyone can point out whats wrong with my questions? is it because of my bad english? post at the wrong section?

Comment: Problem solved, seems like the sites I am visiting is using Tor, and our network firewall is dropping anything related to Tor.

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, seems like the sites I am visiting is using Tor, and our network firewall is dropping anything related to Tor.

Just need to remove the firewall rule that is blocking Tor.